# For each of one element, iterate over a list of other elements. Elements have no sibling/parent relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example code:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWKNRO)

```
<div>
  <button class="mainButton">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement">David</button>
  <div class="subElement">Joe</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="mainButton">AND ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement">Billy</button>
  <div class="subElement">Bob</button>
</div>
```

For each mainButton, I want to iterate over the subElements it corresponds to by either finding the ones below it, or maybe adding some sort of reference?

Can anyone provide any solutions to this issue?

Comment: What do you mean you want to iterate over the subButtons?  You want to click them all when the mainButton is clicked?

Comment: I want to get values off of them. I changed them to divs to make it clear that I only want values off of them.

Comment: I see.  I will post an answer then.  One moment.

Comment: Also, I apologize for leaving this out, but the inner buttons/divs are fairly nested. More so than I showed in my example... Hopefully that doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change anything to your HTML, then I think this would be a way to do it:

```js
$('.mainButton').click(function() {
    var texts = [];
    var $all = $('.mainButton,.subElement');
    $all.slice($all.index(this)+1).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.mainButton')) return false; // break out
        texts.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(texts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="mainButton">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement">David</div>
  <div class="subElement">Joe</div>
</div>

<span>
<div>
  <button class="mainButton">AND ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement">Billy</div>
  <div class="subElement">Bob</div>
</div>
```

This collects all buttons and sub elements in one collection. Then it finds the index where the currently clicked button is positioned in that collection. All elements that come before this index, and also the clicked button itself, are sliced out of the collection. Now all following sub elements are those we are interested in, up until the end of the collection or the next main button.

For this solution it does not matter how deep things are nested, as long as their sequence in the DOM tree is such that all sub elements follow the main button to which they "belong".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to group the subElements with separate class names then use jQuery to get all their values.

```
<div>
  <button class="mainButton" onclick="main1()">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement1">David</button>
  <div class="subElement1">Joe</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="mainButton" onclick="main2()">AND ME!</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="subElement2">Billy</button>
  <div class="subElement2">Bob</button>
</div>
```

I would recommend better class names, but this is just for example.  Then you can grab their values in your js:

```
function main1() {
  var sub1s = $('.subElement1').val();  //this will be an array of their values
}

function main2() {
  var sub2s = $('.subElement2').val();  //also an array
}
```

Comment: So there isn't a way to do it leaving them with the same class names? What I was thinking is that I could put the subElements in a div, give it a classname like "subElements" and then when I click the button, find the NEXT div with "subElements" classname and then access the buttons within that div. Is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, but there would have to be logic to separate the ones you wanted from the ones you didn't want.  Or you could utilize a nested method that grabs .children().